# Watchkit - passing data to source controller

Tags: ios, watchkit

I've currently setup my watch kit to pass data from source to destination using the following:

Source

```
- (IBAction)changeRep {
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"rep", @"button", nil];
[self presentControllerWithName:@"KeyPadInterfaceController" context:dictionary];
```

}

Destination

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
[super awakeWithContext:context];


_parent = [context valueForKey:@"button"];



}
```

I'm trying to get the data now from the destination to source view using the following but dataFromKeyPad in the source view isn't being called.

Source.h

```
@interface WorkoutDetailInterfaceController : WKInterfaceController <KeyPadInterfaceControllerDelegate>{
```

Source.m

```
- (void)dataFromKeyPad:(NSDictionary *)data {
if ([data objectForKey:@"rep"]){
    _repNum = [data valueForKey:@"rep"];
    NSString *repTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ reps", "Number of Reps"), _repNum];
    [self.reps setTitle:repTitle];
} else if ([data objectForKey:@"weight"]) {
    _weightNum = [data valueForKey:@"weight"];
    NSString *weightTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ reps", "Number of Reps"), _weightNum];
    [self.reps setTitle:weightTitle];
}
}
```

Destination.h

```
@protocol KeyPadInterfaceControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)dataFromKeyPad:(NSDictionary *)data;

@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<KeyPadInterfaceControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Destination.m

```
- (IBAction)okAct{
NSDictionary *dictionary;

if ([_parent isEqualToString:@"rep"]) {
    dictionary  = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:_result, @"rep", nil];
} else {
    dictionary =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:_result, @"weight", nil];
}
[self.delegate dataFromKeyPad:dictionary];

[self dismissController];
}
```

When I press the ok button, okAct is called and it goes through everything including dismissController but [self.delegate dataFromKeyPad:dictionary]; doesn't trigger anything in the source view. Any suggestions? I need a solution in Objective C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What value is set in self.delegate of Destination.m? It might contain `nil` in self.delegate.

And You should do as follows in order to prevent crash.

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dataFromKeyPad:)])
{
    [self.delegate dataFromKeyPad:dictionary];
}
```

**Added (7/29):** The way to set self.delegate

Source

```
- (IBAction)changeRep {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"rep", @"button",
                                self, @"delegate",
                                nil];
    [self presentControllerWithName:@"KeyPadInterfaceController" context:dictionary];
}
```

Destination

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context
{
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    // Configure interface objects here.
    if ([context isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        self.delegate = [context objectForKey:@"delegate"];
    } 
}
```

Comment: yes, it looks like you're right, self.delegate is nil. How do I set up the delegate?

I'm calling [self presentControllerWithName:@"KeyPadInterfaceController" context:dictionary]; and I don't know where to set the delegate if it's not called using a segue in watch kit